# Where can I find submission and style guidelines for TUGboat?

Tags: tugboat

I'm looking at writing a short piece for TUGboat. I've read ["The LaTeX2e TUGboat Macros"](http://mirror.ctan.org/pub/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/tugboat/ltubguid.pdf), and ["Quick Tips" and "Advice" in this document](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/location.html) but still have some style/markup questions:

1. Is it necessary or appropriate to include bibliographic citations for `common' programs or packages (such as TeX Live, for example)?
2. Are there any conventionally accepted forms of markup for file and directory names, file extensions, programs and packages, and configuration parameter names?

Comment: @JosephWright (I appreciate this may be marginally off-topic; please close if appropriate.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

the editors will perform any necessary cleanup and return the edited version to you
for approval.  but be warned -- the editors are absolutely beastly about consistency.
they also believe that readers come first, so remember that please.  if you find an
existing article that you like the looks of, you could do worse than use that as a model.

the editors *do* appreciate a nice clean input file that does what it needs to do,
so thanks for asking.

1. if you are recommending a particular package, and a reader is going to have to
   look for it, be kind and give directions, especially if it's not on CTAN.  (this
   is a bit more specific than what you've requested, but who knows who might be
   reading this q&a.)  i think we can assume that anyone reading *TUGboat* itself knows
   enough about TeX to know about TeX Live and CTAN, so no xref needed for anything
   that obvious.
2. for file and directory names, monospace is usual (`\textt` or `\verb+...+`, but
   even better is to categorize such items, and use a command approach to identify
   them, so that if a different presentation is seen to be better for some class, one
   change will take care of all instances); `\usepackage{url}` and `\url{...}`
   can help for longer names, especially when line breaks are involved.
   package names are often set with `\textsf`.  (i see that `\textsf` is also used
   in the guide you cite for environment names.)  consult `sampleart.ltx` linked
   from the "quick tips" to see what's already available for specific categories.

author opinions vary on many things, and the opinions of authors are respected,
as long as what they write is internally consistent and makes sense.  the editors
have this peculiar notion that if they don't understand what is written, then some
reader won't understand either, so they will usually ask the author for clarification.

when your piece is ready to go, send it by e-mail to `tugboat@tug.org`

Comment: Thank you, [B]arbara. As an amateur author, I don't have too many hangups as to my opinions, so that's cool. Once you see the article, I think you'll just love my approach to item 2 :-)